# Initial atom position for molecular dynamics simulation without cristallography data

Tags: molecular-dynamics

When I am using a force field such as the formula [image] it has the terms $d_0$, $\theta_0$ etc. in them.As far as I understand, these are the equilibrium distances, angles... As far as I understand, when I have experimental data, for example a crystallographic structure, I would take this structure, run a relaxation algorithm to find the local minimum of potential energy, and then take the resulting distances and angles as the equilibrium distances. Is this correct so far, or are the equilibrium distances/angles determined differently?
However, I am wondering, how would I get these distances and angles if I only have for example a smiles string, and no initial experimental data? Would I place the atoms according to VSEPR theory and average bond lengths depending on bond type and atom type and then run a conformation search for the torsion angles? Or are there more sophisticated methods to get the geometry? I am particularly interested in the local geometry, so the bond lengths and bond angles, not so much the torsion angles.

Comment: The answer will depend very much on the system you are interested in. It makes a huge difference if you have to find a reasonable starting configuration for $10$ or  $10^5$ atoms.

Comment: Lets say for something like 10-100 atoms. But are the bond lengths and angles (not the torsion angles) really that depended on the size of the molecule? From what I have found so far, force fields always use constants independent of the molecule size for those parameters?

Comment: It is not a matter of size dependence. The problem is just the efficiency of the search for the global minimum as a function of the number of parameters.

Comment: Sure, it is just unclear to me, where these constants $d_0, \theta_0$ come from.

Comment: Material Modeling might be a better place.